Can I integrate Gutenberg on one page only?
We have WooCommerce now which is specially developed and we use a custom design.
But we would like to use a page builder on the product page itself, so that we can set up, correct and add more easily.
Is it therefore possible to only integrate a page builder on only one subpage (product page) and therefore not on all the others.
I also think about the speed of the website here and we don't need it on other subpages.

I'm not 100% with the technical details but AIUI Gutenberg pages are rendered into HTML at design time - it shouldn't actually be slower.

It should be, depending on the builder the methods would differ but you'd need to copy, edit and then add the WooCommerce product page template to your theme/child theme.
